# Simple fragment not displaying?

Tags: android

I have a simple fragment:

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment{

    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

Defined in xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ttsInput"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding it to my main activity:

```
package com.example.texttospeechapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null){
            InputFragment inputFrag = new InputFragment();
            inputFrag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, inputFrag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the XML for main activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Behavior:

1. The activity loads w/o crashing, but the fragment ui isn't displayed.

I'm just getting into fragments. I'm not sure why this isn't working (I just followed the tutorial @ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Corey Horn's answer, I'd like to explain why this is necessary.

For each FragmentTransaction, you need to 1) begin the transaction, 2) do something, and then 3) commit the transaction. Until you commit a transaction, it doesn't take effect. So a common pattern might be:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, inputFrag) // Do as many operations like this as necessary
ft.commit()
```

Hopefully that gives you a better understanding of why you need the extra method!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to change this line

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, inputFrag);
```

To this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, inputFrag).commit();
```